# Using gif as a pause/play button for audio

Tags: javascript, html

I may need a little favor for my project
I'm trying to create a play button based on a gif image. 
How to make it so the gif would function as a play function javascript? 
I'd also want to make it so when I click the gif image it would start playing the animation instead of the gif auto play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply

use the css & javascripts below, however you need to use two different type of pictures, first one would be the gif image, and the other one are a regular img type e.g jpeg or png file.:

And if you don't know already if you're using chrome browser, simply right click on your project page then just click inspect, then choose inspect elements, drag it to the element so you would be able to get the specific css id.

```
<style>


#u11246{
visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

And try this javascript as the follow:

```
<script>
  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
document.getElementById("u11236").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("u11246").style.visibility = "inherit";
  }

                                function stop(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.pause();
document.getElementById("u11236").style.visibility = "inherit";
document.getElementById("u11246").style.visibility = "hidden";
                 }
   </script>
```

And use the following code for the audio.

```
<audio id="audio" src="http://m4a-64.cdn107.com/01/65/45/0165451642.m4a" ></audio>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code snippet, to make a custom play button/element:

```
<button id='playVid'>Play</button>

document.getElementById('playVid').onclick = function (){
    document.getElementById('video').play();
};
```

Check out this info on w3schools.com: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp